# Error: Expect class,delegate,enum or strut

Tags: c#, class, enums, delegates

I get an error when I try to compile my file.

It's my first C# project so I don't know how to fix this.

> Line 10, Column 11: Expect class, delegate, enum or struct

But if I use them it just errors :/

```
using KSP;
using UnityEngine;
using KerbalEconomy;

namespace GetMoney { 

   public float  GetPrositon /* <---- Here it errors */
   {
        Vector3d point;
            double Longitude = vessel.mainBody.GetLongitude(point);
            double Latitude = vessel.mainBody.GetLatitude(point);

            double srfHeight = vessel.mainBody.pqsController.GetSurfaceHeight(
                    QuaternionD.AngleAxis(Longitude, Vector3d.down) *
                    QuaternionD.AngleAxis(Latitude, Vector3d.forward) * Vector3d.right) -
                          vessel.mainBody.pqsController.radius;

            double alt = (Vector3d.Distance(vessel.mainBody.transform.position, point) - vessel.mainBody.Radius); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetPrositon` looks like a method instead of a `class`, `enum` etc..

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. What do you think `GetPrositon` is? Are you trying to declare a type? Or a property? Or something else? What is `vessel`?

Comment: GetProsition just the name of the float and vessel is an thing from Kerbal Space Programm. You can get Informations about the Rocket/Spaceship with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your method in a class in order to define it.

```
using KSP;
using UnityEngine;
using KerbalEconomy;

namespace GetMoney { 

  class MoneyManager
  {
   public float  GetPrositon /* <---- Here it errors */
   {
        Vector3d point;
            double Longitude = vessel.mainBody.GetLongitude(point);
            double Latitude = vessel.mainBody.GetLatitude(point);

            double srfHeight = vessel.mainBody.pqsController.GetSurfaceHeight(
                    QuaternionD.AngleAxis(Longitude, Vector3d.down) *
                    QuaternionD.AngleAxis(Latitude, Vector3d.forward) * Vector3d.right) -
                          vessel.mainBody.pqsController.radius;

            double alt = (Vector3d.Distance(vessel.mainBody.transform.position, point) - vessel.mainBody.Radius); 
    }
}
```

}

You can read more about the OO paradigm here:
[Object-Oriented Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx)